Could this method create general intelligence?

Periodically mutate the neural network
Random logics are created on the neural network
Survival of the fittest occurs as random logics interact with each other
Evolution occurs
Evolved organisms have general intelligence to respond to random logics


A big part of the question whether or not this kind of learning could yield any sort of intelligence is the fitness function. Besides, what do you mean by "logics"?

What you have basically described is NeuroEvolution of Augmenting Topologies (NEAT).  It has yet to achieve general intelligence.  Although it has been used many times to tackle specific problems.
Evolutionary algorithms are, as of yet, fairly sample inefficient.  So while it may be possible to evolve intelligence this way, it may not happen on a reasonable timescale.

Rather than selecting a neural network based on a fitness function, survival of the fittest occurs among logics within a neural network.

Another big drawback of evolutionary algorithms is their computational inefficiency. In every generation, I'd need a population of hundreds or thousands of models interact with each other and their environment some time to find the fittest individuals.

@Displayname if you look up Neuroevolution on Wikipedia you’ll get a history of the field back to 1994.   Weights, structure and parameters have all been tried over the years.  Not that AGI won’t come from this, just that it hasn’t yet.
